# Calling outside function file in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am making a plugin that calls a customised library which contains a list of functions.

I, first saved this library outside the plugins folder, then inside it to see if it changes something. The function is exceuted but getting the message `"Global name 'qgis' is not defined"`.

Here is the sample code:

Code 1: the run of plugin

```py
sys.path.append(r'C:/Users/Nekkini/.qgis2/python/plugins/lib')
import lib_ICT
self.dlg.show()
result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            FCI = str(self.dlg.RefCMD.toPlainText())
            if FCI == qgis.core.NULL or FCI == "" :
                FCI = 'F99999jjmmaa'
            else :
                FCI = FCI.upper()
            lib_ICT.shpblo(FCI)
```

Code 2: my library called lib_ICT

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
# import qgis.utils
def shpblo(FCI):
    print 'hello'
    canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
    lay = dict((k.name(), i) for (i,k) in enumerate(canvas.layers()))
    folder = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./") + "/"

    Dossier_Principal = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")
    layers = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()

    ...
```

As you can see, I am calling `qgis.utils.iface` with no success. I am using QGIS 2.14.

Comment: Are you intending to use the same library in more plugins? If not, you can distribute it with your plugin in the same directory and do "import .lib_ICT"  (notice the starting dot) If that works, something goes wrong when you set the search path.

Comment: When you saved it inside your plugin file, did you still do the sys.path.append or did you call it as .lib_ICT?

Comment: I would like to save these functions in a different folder than the plugins one’s just for confidentiality purpose. I am trying to avoid that some people of our staff from stealing our knowledge !